# How to add unique auto-increment number on url before slug

Tags: url-rewriting

How to add an auto-increment number for each post's URL just before slug.

For example, the URLs will be:

```
https://website.com/1/post_name
https://website.com/2/post_name_2nd_post
...
https://website.com/999/post_name
```

Comment: have you tried putting the post ID in the permalink on the settings page?

Comment: Post ID will not work, as client wants to decide from which number he wants to use for auto increment. Then all the published posts will have auto-incremented(+1) numbers for them. For example, client decides to start with 1000, then first post will have number 1000, 2nd = 1001 and so on.